# how to connect FBChat with android app

Tags: java, android

I want to connect FBChat with my app there is a code that im using to connect plz bt it is not connecting plz give me any solution. There is no any error but" Unfortunately app has stopped"

```
FBConsoleChatApp.java


 package com.fb.xmppchat.app;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.fb.xmppchat.helper.CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism;
import com.fb.xmppchat.helper.FBMessageListener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

import org.apache.commons.collections.BidiMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections.bidimap.DualHashBidiMap;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;

public class FBConsoleChatApp {

public static final String FB_XMPP_HOST = "chat.facebook.com";
public static final int FB_XMPP_PORT = 5222;

private ConnectionConfiguration config;
 private XMPPConnection connection;
private BidiMap friends = new DualHashBidiMap();
private FBMessageListener fbml;

public void connect() throws XMPPException {
   ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("chat.facebook.com", 5222);
     config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
     config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
     config.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(true);
     config.setTruststorePath("/system/etc/security/cacerts.bks");
     config.setTruststorePassword("changeit");
     config.setTruststoreType("bks");
     config.setSendPresence(false);
     try {
         SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
         sc.init(null, MemorizingTrustManager.getInstanceList(this),
           new java.security.SecureRandom());
         config.setCustomSSLContext(sc);
     } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
         Log.w("TAG", "Unable to use MemorizingTrustManager", e);
     }
     XMPPConnection xmpp = new XMPPConnection(config);
     try {
         xmpp.connect();
         xmpp.login("facebookusername", "****"); // Here you have to used only
         facebookusername from facebookusername@chat.facebook.com
         Roster roster = xmpp.getRoster();
         Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
         System.out.println("Connected!");
         System.out.println("\n\n" + entries.size() + " buddy(ies):");
         // shows first time onliners---->
         String temp[] = new String[50];
         int i = 0;
         for (RosterEntry entry : entries) {
             String user = entry.getUser();
             Log.i("TAG", user);
         }
     } catch (XMPPException e) {
         xmpp.disconnect();
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     }

   public void disconnect() {
  if ((connection != null) && (connection.isConnected())) {
     Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.unavailable);
     presence.setStatus("offline");
     connection.disconnect(presence);
      }
   }

 public boolean login(String userName, String password) 
  throws XMPPException {
  if ((connection != null) && (connection.isConnected())) {
     connection.login(userName, password);
     return true;
     }
   return false;
  }

  public String readInput() throws IOException {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  return br.readLine();
    }

  public void showMenu() {
  System.out.println("Please select one of the following menu.");
  System.out.println("1. List of Friends online");
  System.out.println("2. Send Message");
  System.out.println("3. EXIT");
  System.out.print("Your choice [1-3]: ");
   }

  public void getFriends() {
  if ((connection != null) && (connection.isConnected())) {
     Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
     int i = 1;
     for (RosterEntry entry : roster.getEntries()) {
        Presence presence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
        if ((presence != null) 
           && (presence.getType() != Presence.Type.unavailable)) {
           friends.put("#" + i, entry);
           System.out.println(entry.getName() + "(#" + i + ")");
           i++;
        }
     }
     fbml.setFriends(friends);
      }
   }

  public void sendMessage() throws XMPPException
 , IOException {
  System.out.println("Type the key number of your friend (e.g. #1)
  and the text that you wish to    send !");
  String friendKey = null;
  String text = null;
  System.out.print("Your friend's Key Number: ");
  friendKey = readInput();
  System.out.print("Your Text message: ");
  text = readInput();
  sendMessage((RosterEntry) friends.get(friendKey), text);
  }

  public void sendMessage(final RosterEntry friend, String text) 
 throws XMPPException {
  if ((connection != null) && (connection.isConnected())) {
     ChatManager chatManager = connection.getChatManager();
     Chat chat = chatManager.createChat(friend.getUser(), fbml);
     chat.sendMessage(text);
     System.out.println("Your message has been sent to "
        + friend.getName());
  }
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (args.length == 0) {
    System.err.println("Usage: java FBConsoleChatApp [username_facebook] [password]");
    System.exit(-1);
  }

  String username = args[0];
  String password = args[1];

  FBConsoleChatApp app = new FBConsoleChatApp();

  try {
     app.connect();
     if (!app.login(username, password)) {
        System.err.println("Access Denied...");
        System.exit(-2);
     }
     app.showMenu();
     String data = null;
     menu:
     while((data = app.readInput().trim()) != null) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(data.charAt(0))) {
           System.out.println("Invalid input.Only 1-3 is allowed !");
           app.showMenu();
           continue;
        }
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(data);
        if ((choice != 1) && (choice != 2) && (choice != 3)) {
           System.out.println("Invalid input.Only 1-3 is allowed !");
           app.showMenu();
           continue;
        }
        switch (choice) {
           case 1: app.getFriends();
                   app.showMenu();
                   continue menu;
           case 2: app.sendMessage();
                   app.showMenu();
                   continue menu;
           default: break menu;
        }
     }
     app.disconnect();
  } catch (XMPPException e) {
    if (e.getXMPPError() != null) {
       System.err.println("ERROR-CODE : " + e.getXMPPError().getCode());
       System.err.println("ERROR-CONDITION : " + e.getXMPPError().getCondition());
       System.err.println("ERROR-MESSAGE : " + e.getXMPPError().getMessage());
       System.err.println("ERROR-TYPE : " + e.getXMPPError().getType());
    }
    app.disconnect();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    app.disconnect();
  }
  }
} 


FBMessageListener.java

package com.fb.xmppchat.helper;

import org.apache.commons.collections.BidiMap;
import org.apache.commons.collections.MapIterator;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManagerListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.MessageListener;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Message;

public class FBMessageListener implements MessageListener, Runnable {

   private FBMessageListener fbml = this;
  private XMPPConnection conn;
  private BidiMap friends;

  public FBMessageListener(XMPPConnection conn) {
  this.conn = conn;
  new Thread(this).start();
   }

   public void setFriends(BidiMap friends) {
  this.friends = friends;
   }

   public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
   System.out.println();
   MapIterator it = friends.mapIterator();
   String key = null;
   RosterEntry entry = null;
   while (it.hasNext()) {
     key = (String) it.next();
     entry = (RosterEntry) it.getValue();
     if (entry.getUser().equalsIgnoreCase(chat.getParticipant())) {
        break;
     }
   }
   if ((message != null) && (message.getBody() != null)) {
     System.out.println("You've got new message from " + entry.getName() 
        + "(" + key + ") :");
     System.out.println(message.getBody());
     System.out.print("Your choice [1-3]: ");
   }
  }

  public void run() {
   conn.getChatManager().addChatListener(
     new ChatManagerListener() {
        public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
           if (!createdLocally) {
              chat.addMessageListener(fbml);
           }
        }
     }
   );
  }
}


CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism.java



package com.fb.xmppchat.helper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPException;
  import org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism;

 public class CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism extends SASLMechanism {

   public CustomSASLDigestMD5Mechanism(SASLAuthentication saslAuthentication) {
  super(saslAuthentication);
  }

   @Override
   public void authenticate(String username, String host, String password)
   throws IOException, XMPPException {
   this.authenticationId = username;
   this.password = password;
   this.hostname = host;

  String[] mechanisms = { getName() };
  Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
  sc = de.measite.smack.Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp", host, props, this);
  super.authenticate();
  }


   public void authenticate(String username, String host, org.apache.harmony.javax.
security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler cbh)
 throws IOException, XMPPException {
  String[] mechanisms = { getName() };
  Map<String, String> props = new HashMap<String, String>();
  sc = org.apache.harmony.javax.security.sasl.Sasl.createSaslClient(mechanisms, null, "xmpp",  
     host, props, cbh);
  super.authenticate();
  }

 protected String getName() {
 return "DIGEST-MD5";
 }
}
```

Comment: It does not look like an Android related class. Android won't run a main method.  Try removing that and creating a propper Android project.  That'll do the trick.

Comment: can any one share me project like that plz

Comment: I thought this was kind oof a code generator request!!

Comment: No not at all i want just a sample!

Comment: Ok,  you want someone to solve THE problem...  That does not mean you've tested a connection and it did not work...  I'm tired of people just posting the general thing and hoping somebody will post the whole solution...  And,  even,  asking for people to share the whole project by private email...  Daaaaarn thing...  Please,  say where is the trouble,  the code failing and what you've been testing to solve by yourself.

Comment: And,  please,  stackusers...  Don't feed these behaviours just because you love to have reputation because you're turning a useful forum-solving-issue tool into a lazy programmer code generation tool!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've googled for your code and it is a copy paste from online code you've found.  Pleasd vote negagives to this guys lazy programmer question.